# Is it possible to prevent iframe content from escaping into main page using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

It is often done by code like this:

```
if ( window.parent.frames.length>0 )  {}  // check how many frames, if none do nothing
else {
   window.location="[new destination]";  // else change the current location
}
```

But I want to prevent iframe content from knowing that it is on the iframe.
I am writing a php proxy and content will be from the same domain and I know that I have an option to remove instances of escaping code one by one using server side code but maybe is there an option to do it in JS.