# Why is Chrome redirecting to URL of iframe onload?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, webkit, cross-domain

I have a div with an iframe in it, and the iframe loads a page from another site (cross-domain). When the page loads in firefox it works fine and shows the page with the iframe in the div. However in Chrome, it automatically redirects to the iframe  URL when the page loads.  Any idea why this is happening and if it's possible to do what I'm trying to do in Chrome?

Notes: I'm not trying to do any cross-domain communication, just want to let users access the other site from within a page on my site. This also happens in Safari, so maybe it's a webkit thing.

Comment: Does it happen on every url? Maybe this one particular site has "escape-from-iframe" code?

Comment: No it doesn't. Yea, I realized that a little while after I posted this, certain URLs from other domains work, so it must be that. I'm not sure how that's done so I didn't know what to look for, but I can figure it out.

Comment: Answer to both your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002712/is-it-possible-to-prevent-iframe-content-from-escaping-into-main-page-using-js

Answer (score 14):

Sandboxed iframe may be solution to your problem. It's supported by both Safari and Chrome, and will not effect Firefox<sup>1</sup>. You can use it like so:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts" src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
```

By not adding `allow-top-navigation` there you are preventing an iframe to redirect the whole page.
You can read more about it on [W3C.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox).

---

<sup>1</sup> Starting from version 17, Firefox also supports sandboxed iframe.